# using toarray() with onehotencoding during data preprocessing

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, artificial-intelligence, data-science

I am new to machine learning. I have one doubt: why use `toarray()` with onehotencoding while not with label encoding here. I am not getting any idea. pls someone help.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
label_encoder_x = LabelEncoder()
x[:, 0] = label_encoder_x.fit_transform(x[:, 0])
onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features= [0])
x = onehotencoder.fit_transform(x).toarray()
label_encoder_y = LabelEncoder()
y = label_encoder_y.fit_transform(y)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.fit_transform), `OneHotEncoder` will by default return a sparse matrix, which is less intuitive to work with. As a minimal example:

```
>>> df
   0
0  2
1  2
2  2
3  1
4  1
5  2
6  2
7  1
8  1
9  1

onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features= [0])

>>> onehotencoder.fit_transform(df[0].values.reshape(1,-1))
<1x10 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 10 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
```

However if you call `toarray`, you get something that is easier to work with, or at least easier to comprehend:

```
>>> onehotencoder.fit_transform(df[0].values.reshape(1,-1)).toarray()
array([[1., 2., 2., 1., 1., 2., 2., 1., 1., 1.]])
```

An alternative is to use `sparse = False` when you create your OneHotEncoder, and then it creates a dense array by default:

```
onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features= [0], sparse=False)

>>> onehotencoder.fit_transform(df[0].values.reshape(1,-1))
array([[1., 2., 2., 1., 1., 2., 2., 1., 1., 1.]])
```

Comment: @sacul..thanx dude for the information.I got it now